# Handle multiple incoming requests with Python tornado

Tags: python, tornado

I have a code which works fine for one user request. However, it can not handle multiple requests, it waits for one requests to finish and then handles second requests. How can I handle multiple requests concurrently.

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
import tornado.websocket
from tornado import gen
import random
import time
import sys
```

This is a class that simulates some incoming data.

```
class Message():


    def __init__(self):
        self.dct = {'foo': 0, 'bar': 0, 'durrr': 0}
        self.keys = list(self.dct.keys())


    def update_key(self):
        dct_key = random.choice(self.keys)
        ran = random.choice(range(10, 21))
        self.dct[dct_key] += ran
        if self.dct[dct_key] >= 100:
            self.dct[dct_key] = 'Loading Completed'
            self.keys.remove(dct_key)


    def is_completed(self):
        return True if self.keys == [] else False


    def __str__(self):
        strng = ''
        for key, value in self.dct.items():
            if type(value) == int:
                strng += '{}: {}% completed.<br>'.format(key, value)
            else:
                strng += '{}: {}<br>'.format(key, value)
        return strng
```

This class sends data through socket.

```
class EchoWebSocket(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):


    def open(self):
        print("WebSocket opened")


    def on_message(self, message):
        msg = Message()
        while not msg.is_completed():
            msg.update_key()
            try:
                fut = self.write_message('Download progress for user xyz:<br>{}Download in progress! Please wait...<br>'.format(msg.__str__()))
                print(fut)
            except tornado.websocket.WebSocketClosedError:
                print('WebSocket is closed')
                break
            time.sleep(1)
        self.write_message('Download progress for user xyz:<br>{}Download completed. You may proceed.'.format(msg.__str__()))
        #sys.exit('Program terminated.')


    def on_close(self):
        print("WebSocket closed")
```

Main class is simple. Renders some html. The main engine is in EchoWebSocket.

```
class Main(tornado.web.RequestHandler):


    def get(self):
        self.render('counter2.html', title='Websockets')


application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r"/", Main),
    (r"/websocket", EchoWebSocket),
])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

And the html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
   <head>
       <title>Tornado Test</title>
       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>    
            $(document).ready(function () {
                var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8888/websocket");
                ws.onopen = function() {
                    ws.send("Hello, world");
                };
                ws.onmessage = function (evt) {
                    document.getElementById("myDIV").innerHTML = evt.data + "<br>";
                };
            });
        </script>
        <div id="myDIV"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `time.sleep(1)` is a blocking function. Use `await gen.sleep(1)` instead.

Comment: @xyres It works like charm now. Make it as answer so I can mark it and upvote it.

Comment: Added an answer. Thanks for the incentive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `time.sleep(1)`. But `time.sleep` is a blocking function, that means it will stop the whole server and nothing else will be able to run during that time.

This has also been mentioned in Tornado [`FAQs` page](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/faq.html#why-isn-t-this-example-with-time-sleep-running-in-parallel).

What you need is an asynchronous sleep function. Tornado has `gen.sleep`. Use it like this:

```
async def my_func():
    ...
    await gen.sleep(1)
```